# Edit more than one color at once in Edit Colors

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a Sun vector that is MANY shades of Orange and Yellow. I would like to make the orange swirl in the middle shades of yellow instead. When I lasso the middle and go to edit colors, there are about 50-60 color bars of orange. Is there a way to select multiple orange bars and select a yellow for all selected? Am I going about this the completely wrong way? I have noticed with watercolor vectors there are SO  many little objects, its just impossible to change colors using the layer paths without having a ton of objects to alter.

[image]

Comment: Using the **Magic Wand** to select the orange shapes, changing the **Fill Color Tolerance** is not an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

A - Use the magic wand tool to select the desired color;
    Press Enter to show its options and play with the tolerance values.

B - Open the recolor artwork panel and click the Edit button.

C - Check: Link harmnony color. This will lock all color positions.

D - Drag any color circle to change it and all the other colors, respecting their positions. You can also drag the Hue, Saturation and Brightness slider.

Image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think tinkering with hundreds of small objects who nobody knows personally, is a little ineffective method.

If you haven't it as a high resolution raster image, make one. Copy it to photoshop where you have prepared say 1500 x 1500 pixels empty image and paste it on as pixels.

In photoshop you easily with the quick selection tool select the wrong colored rings and recolor them:

[image]

(sorry for my bad quality screenshot)

Then you copy and paste it back to illustrator and live trace it again say, to 100 colors.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the **Recolor Artwork** dialog window....

- Use the `Color` drop down to reduce the number of colors. This will auto-merge various colors...
- You can drag colors between the color bars on the left to merge them...
- You can add more colors to further merge....

[image]